# Does PHPStorm display PL/SQL(triggers, views, etc)

Tags: plsql, phpstorm

I know that I've used it in the past and it did display the triggers but now it seams that it's not working. Does anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 0):

the Database Navigator plugin does it. In case they disappeared all of a sudden, maybe there has been a permission change on the DB account you're using. Maybe the account lacks the permission to browse PL/SQL objects and so on.

Comment: It's the root user, I don't think it's necessary